# How can i save png images in sdl?

Tags: c++, png, sdl

ok so i want to save images in sdl.
i only know how to save stuff in .txt files.
theoreticlly i could take all the bits of the surface and save them in the .txt file and later load all those bits into a surface manually.
but i don't want to do that because a surface in sdl has to go threw some certain processes witch i don't really know what they do.
like every surface has to go through the SDL_DisplayFormat(SDL_Surface *) function.
and if i load functions threw .txt i won't be able to do that.
and there is probablly a simple function to do this so i want to take the easy way.
so where can i get a function that saves a surface to a png file(preferred SDL function)

Answer (score 0):

Use that one to save the Screen as Bitmap.

```
SDL_SaveBMP(main_global_stuff.sdl.surface, screenshot_filename);
```

I just looked quickly; with SDL_Image you're able to load png-files. Take a look here for [more solutions and librarys](http://www.libsdl.org/libraries.php?order=name&category=-1&completed=0&os=-1&match_name=SDL_&perpage=25).
[SDL_Image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)